# Shortcut to settings android

Tags: android, settings, shortcut

I'm interested about how is possible create a shortcut to different items of settings in android devices.
Specifically to advances settings of mobile data.
I want to do an app that allows user a quick access to switch menu 2g-3g.
I know that the app dosen't do switch, I only want the shorcut to this menu.
I don't know how It's made!
I'm very glad if somebody help me!
Thanks a lot!!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    Button boton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);
        boton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.boton)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS));
        }
    }
}
```

I do this code by the explanation of Seraphim but dosen't work.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is what are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

To switch to the 2G/3G settings page use this code inside the Button click handler:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS));
```

or others, look at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Other interesting are:

```
android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS
android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS
android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS 
android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that I can include that Intent in a button a it will show that menu, right?

Comment: No, if you need to display a menu you need to code more. Do you want to display a context menu or a new activity with a listview?

Answer (score 0):

i would like to suggest u that refer this three link(***[FIRST](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)***,***[SECOND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html)***,***[THIRD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html)***) and u would be able to change most of the settings by ur own . **ANDROID SETTINGS** mostly stores there respective values to this three tables.

If you want to enable or disable GPS than use

```
Settings.Secure.setLocationProviderEnabled(cr, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
```

Comment: No, I want android.provider.Settings but for the moment dosen't work. Thanks for your reply!!!

Comment: this three table contains most of the fields of the settings. And u can change and save them over there. Use methods putInt nd all to modify available settings